# $n^{th}$ root of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What conditions do I need on a matrix $A$ in order to know an $n^{th}$ root exists. In other words there is a matrix $B$ such that $B^n=A$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: One sufficient condition is if $A$ can be written as $A=\exp(M)$.

Comment: @Berci So is there an easy test to apply to $A$ to determine if it can be written $\exp(M)$? Obviously if we can diagonalize $A$ we can take any root we want, but can we weaken this condition?

Comment: Continue with your diagonalization idea.  If the matrix is diagonalizable can you say something about its roots?

Comment: @BettyMock Sure if the matrix is diagonalizable the existence of the root will depend on the sign of the eigenvalues(depending on the parity of $n$) and we can use the diagonalization to get the root. I guess what I'm getting at is can a non-diagonalizable matrix have an $n^{th}$ root?

Comment: If $A=\exp(M)$, then $A$ is invertible. However, I don't know if the exponential map is surjective

Comment: @MTurgeon Matrix exponential map is surjective to invertible matrices.

Comment: @mtiano Why would the existence of the root depend on the sign of the eigenvalues?  Are we not admitting complex numbers? Also, if the matrix is not invertible the nth roots are still there even though those entries are zero; and the matrix is not expressible in exponential form.  As per answer below, I was moving towards Jordan form -- if you can find the roots of a diagonalizable matrix, so too can you find the roots of the matrix in Jordan form.

Answer (score 3):

If your matrix is invertable and you can get it into [Jordan Normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) you can take the logarithm of a matrix using the techniques described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix), and then exponentiate, taking advantage of the power rule for exponentials in the usual way. (If A is your matrix, then $\exp(\frac{1}{n}\log(A)) = A^\frac{1}{n}$)

Comment: This applies only to invertible matrices.

Comment: This is true. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\in \textrm{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ is a nonzero nilpotent matrix, then a square-root of the matrix $A$ is not defined.

To see this,

Suppose that $A=\pmatrix{{0}&{1}\\{0}&{0}}=B^2$, then $B$ is nilpotent as well.

Then $B$ is similar to either $A$ or $O$(zero-matrix), by considering Jordan block.

But, in either case, $B^2=O$, which is not possible.

Comment: But what can we say about the general case, not just the square root.

Comment: For this particular $A$, and for any $n\geq 2$, $A=B^n$ is impossible.

Comment: You've written $A=B^2$ here, which really leads one to want to claim that $B = \sqrt{A}$ for all practical purposes.

Comment: This is "Proof by contradiction". I am not claiming that $B=\sqrt{A}$.

Comment: Great! Can this argument be extended to larger matrices?

Comment: I think it is possible, but just too much cases to consider.

Comment: If the dimension is not large, such as $3$, then there are two similarity classes of nilpotent matrices, that has square root. However, if dimension gets larger, then it would be difficult.