# How to solve the matrix equation $AB^n=C$ for $B$?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, algorithms, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

As stated in the title, the matrix equation is as follows:

$$ AB^n = C $$

where $A$ and $C$ are known matrices of size $1 \times m$.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_m
\end{bmatrix}B^n=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 & c_2 & \dots & c_m
\end{bmatrix} $$

The power $n$ is also known. The problem is to find **any** matrix $B$ of size $m \times m$ which solves this equation. Are there any algorithms or numerical methods that can successfully tackle this problem?

Comment: Find any invertible matrix D such that $D^T A^T = C^T$, then solve $B^n = D$ using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646919/nth-root-of-a-matrix

Comment: What is the underlying field? $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$ or something else?

Comment: @10762409 Doesn't this work only when D has positive eigenvalues? When a negative eigenvalue appears, the logarithm becomes non-principal, and the exponentiation doesn't result in the original matrix (at least according to Matlab).

Comment: @user1551 Technically, in the original equation, all the values are integers. However, I don't think this is solvable with integer arithmetic, so let's say they are real numbers.